# How to assign multiple select query values into declared variables in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to assign multiple select query values into declared variables in a stored procedure?

This works

```
SELECT @id = USER_ID 
FROM USERS 
WHERE EMAIL=@EMAIL
```

but I need something like this

```
SELECT @id = USER_ID, @corp = CORPORATE_ID 
FROM USERS 
WHERE EMAIL = @EMAIL
```

above query doesn't work (which means I cannot assign multiple values), is there any way to make possible this thing?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: "doesn't work " <----- not the best description...

Comment: which means i cannot assign multiple values

Comment: @FazalMohamed, what happens? (an error generated or values not assigned or etc.) Syntactically query seems correct.

Comment: yeah there is no error in quary but values are not assigned to declared variables..

Comment: Does query `SELECT USER_ID, CORPORATE_ID FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = @EMAIL` return rows ?

Comment: yes, it is working fine

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work?? It works **just fine**! There must be something else that's wrong with your tables and/or code.

Comment: ok, i'll try it again now

Comment: @FazalMohamed this should work fine

Comment: yeah, thanks to all of you , i tried an example it is working fine there might be other problem in my code

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you're doing - but selecting multiple values and assigning them to multiple variables in T-SQL works **just fine** - inside or outside of a stored procedure.

If you have the AdventureWorks sample database - try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAddressTypeDetails (@AddressTypeID INT, @Name VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT, @Modified DATETIME OUTPUT)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT
        @Name = Name, @Modified = ModifiedDate
    FROM
        [Person].[AddressType]
    WHERE
        [AddressTypeID] = @AddressTypeId
END
```

and then execute this stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @AddressTypeID INT
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @Modified DATETIME

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.
SET @AddressTypeID = 5

EXECUTE [dbo].[GetAddressTypeDetails] @AddressTypeID, @Name OUTPUT, @Modified OUTPUT

SELECT 
    @Name, @Modified
```

and you'll get the output of

```
Shipping   2002-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

No problems here.....